# App doesn't launch in emulator, error says- io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1 lambda$0 INFO: Detected dialect: W3C

Tags: appium, mobile-automation

I am new in mobile automation and first time trying to launch the app in emulator. Just the mobile screen blinks but My app doesn't get launched. Can anyone help me..

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

public class AppTest {
    


    public static AppiumDriver<MobileElement>appium;

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File app = new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\iTest-20.07(43).apk");
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP,app.getAbsolutePath());
        caps.setCapability("deviceName","emulator-5554");
        caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.0");
        caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.google.android.apps.nexuslaunch");
        caps.setCapability("appActivity", "com.google.android.apps.nexuslaunch.NexusLaunchActivity");
        caps.setCapability("noReset", "false");
        caps.setCapability("disableWindowAnimation", false);


        try {
            appium = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Application Launched");
    }
}
```

Result:

```
io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1 lambda$0
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
```

Comment: What you show is not an error. Just INFO message.

Comment: You have Just intialized the `AndroidDriver` class with `appium` object. You have to do something with this object based on your test cases. I think there is no error occurred it is the log from the appium executer.

Answer (score 0):

Try running these commands

```
adb uninstall io.appium.settings
adb uninstall io.appium.uiautomator2.server
adb uninstall io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test
adb uninstall io.appium.unlock
```